# Return only the lowest value after RANK()

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, rank

I have created certain "cases" using:

```
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY name, A, B, some_value) as case_id
```

Now I need to create ranks within each case_id where name can appear only once and lowest rank should be assigned to the lowest some_value.

Here is data example:

[image: data]

And the desired output:

[image]

Comment: You mean you want the lowest `case_id` value after? Example data and expected output would really help out here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from ( 

    Select Name, A, B, some_value, case_id 
    , ROWNO() over (partition by case_id, Name order by some_value) as R1
    from (
        Select 'SF' as Name, 'y' as A, 'n' as B, 120 as some_value, 1 as case_id
        union all Select 'NY' as Name, 'y' as A, 'n' as B, 150 as some_value, 1 as case_id
        union all Select 'LA' as Name, 'y' as A, 'n' as B, 155 as some_value, 1 as case_id
        union all Select 'SF' as Name, 'y' as A, 'n' as B, 160 as some_value, 1 as case_id
        union all Select 'SF' as Name, 'n' as A, 'y' as B, 110 as some_value, 5 as case_id
        union all Select 'NY' as Name, 'n' as A, 'y' as B, 120 as some_value, 5 as case_id
        union all Select 'LA' as Name, 'n' as A, 'y' as B, 125 as some_value, 5 as case_id
        union all Select 'LA' as Name, 'n' as A, 'y' as B, 140 as some_value, 5 as case_id
        union all Select 'NY' as Name, 'n' as A, 'y' as B, 155 as some_value, 5 as case_id
    ) testdata

    ) data
Where R1 = 1
order by case_id, some_value
```